# Embeded YouTube video must be autoplayed with voice..?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-chrome, youtube-api

I'm working on a Web Application and our client is demanding that video must be autoplayed with voice when a user vists it.
Here is what I'm doing:

HTML:

```
       <embed id="video1"   src="" wmode="transparent" type="application/x- 
       shockwave-flash" width="538" height="580"  allowfullscreen="true" 
       title="Adobe Flash Player">
       </embed>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {
            var url = "<?= $pagedata->aboutus_videourl;?>";
            url = url.split('v=')[1];
            $("#video")[0].src = "https://www.youtube.com/v/" + url 
             + "&mute=1" + "?autoplay=0" ;
            };

       function autoplay(){
       $('#video1').attr('src',$('#video').attr("src").replace("autoplay=0", 
       "autoplay=1"));
          }
```

If I set &mute=0 the video autoplays with voice but not in chrome. So how I can force video to autoplay with voice in chrome also.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: for testing anybody can visit it

Comment: First of all - really, you are still embedding the _flash_ version? Why? Who (of your site’s visitors) even still has flash on their computer these days …? Secondly, modern browsers don’t necessarily _allow_ for what your client wants to begin with. _Because_ so many websites simply go on the user’s nerves with their autoplay videos that no one really asked for, they place certain retrictions on this - like allowing autoplay only in muted state in certain situations.

Comment: I was embeding the flash version just for testing. I already have told all these aspects to client but he is forcing me to acieve this.

Answer (score 0):

```
+ "&mute=1" + "?autoplay=0" ;
```

Your querystring starts from autoplay. Querystrings start with ?. Additional queries are added with &. Mute attribute is probably being ignore as it is before the start of your querystring. Try the below. Also why you setting the src with js. can't you just set it in the html tag

```
+ "?mute=0&autoplay=1" ;
```

**Updated**

Try adding `autoplay='true' muted='false'` in the embed tag

Here is why chrome doesn't allow autoplay with sound as mentioned by @misorude

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Comment: no i can't set it with html. There are some other limitation

Comment: Hey. I made a mistake try + "?mute=0&autoplay=1" ; if not try the changes to the embed tag. Also added link that explains why chrome wont support.

Comment: yes i know why chrome wont support it. But our client is forcing for this

Comment: Then he will have to take it up with Google

Comment: haahah...exactly

Comment: if i set muted="false" or mute=1 video does not autoplayed neither mute nor with voice

Comment: Ah thank you Google  Well im sorry I could not help. If Google says no. I think it will be very difficult to get around it. 